# Django Mongoengine leading whitespace being stripped

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongoengine, restframeworkmongoengine

I have a small issue that I'm struggling to find a solution on.

Currently when I receive the result from a POST with JSON data back from Django(1.11.5), all leading whitespaces in some of the values are completely gone but all in between the words saved.

Is there a setting for MongoEngine that stops this on StringFields?

For example:
I send with requests in Python(3.6.2):

```
{'foo': '  bar'}
```

I get back from the request content:

```
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

I'm using MongoEngine (0.14.3), django-restframwork-mongoengine (3.3.1) and viewsets.ModelViewSet btw :)

Comment: Found that I had a `.strip()` on the string. made this into `.rstrip()` and all presented well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I had a `.strip()` on the string. made this into `.rstrip()` and all presented well. :)